# Why is there "\n" all over my JSON from REST endpoint in Go?

Tags: json, rest, go

I want to return some JSON that's fetched from an API, and thrown up to a REST endpoint in my Go program. The data is fine as it comes in, but somehow, the encoding messes up the JSON?

Sample code:

```
var stockSymbols = []string{
    "GOOGL",
    "TSLA",
    "AAPL",
    }

var MarketDataMap = make(map[int]interface{})


func GetStockMarketData() {

    for index, stockSymbol := range stockSymbols {
        var requestLink = fmt.Sprintf(
            "http://somelinkhere/API%sand%v",
            stockSymbol, apiKey)

        response, err := http.Get(requestLink)

        fmt.Println("Getting data for.. " + stockSymbol)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("The HTTP request failed with error %s\n", err)
        } else {
            data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
            MarketDataMap[index] = string(data)
        }

    }

    fmt.Println("recursing...")
    time.AfterFunc(time.Second * 10, GetStockMarketData)
}
```

If you print MarketDataMap here, it will look fine.

However, when exposed in the controller, it completely messes up and adds `\n` everywhere:

```
func stocksHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    enc := json.NewEncoder(w)
    err := enc.Encode(MarketDataMap)

    fmt.Println("request made")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}


// Expose controller at http://localhost:8081/
func StockMarketDataController() {
    http.HandleFunc("/stocks", stocksHandler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}
```

Clearly the problem is with the encoding, how can I avoid using is that way?

The data is very unreadable, even by JSON plugins, example:

```
{"0":"{\n    \"Meta Data\": {\n        \"1. Information\": \"Monthly Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes\",\n        \"2. Symbol\": \"GOOGL\",\n        \"3. Last Refreshed\": \"2018-01-04 14:11:29\",\n        \"4. Time Zone\": \"US/Eastern\"\n    },\n    \"Monthly Time Series\": {\n        \"2018-01-04\": {\n
```

How do I escape all these `\n`'s? Why are they there, and how do I change my controller so they won't be created?

Comment: Just don't pretty print your JSON and _please_: Use json.Marshal instead of a json.Encoder.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use json.Marshal in my context?

Comment: As in a school example of how to capture my MarketDataMap and return it in the response?

Comment: @Volker, why `json.Marshal` instead of `json.Encoder`? Just for the error handling? `Encoder` is more efficient, especially with large payloads.

Comment: @Adrian Encoder and Decoder are intended to serialize and deserialize _streams_ of objects, not single objects. Marshal and Unmarshal are for single objects. OP's data doesn't look "large".

Comment: They're *capable* of serializing and deserializing streams of objects, but they're also perfectly capable of serializing and deserializing single objects, with no penalty, and using less memory to do it because the entire JSON doesn't have to be held in a byte slice all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as the result of `http://somelinkhere/` is JSON itself, so you have JSON in a Go string. However, you try to encode the JSON string again into JSON in `stocksHandler`, so you're "nesting JSON in JSON." However, the object you are trying to encode is NOT an object, so any JSON library expecting to read a true JSON object will fail.

If you were to add `{"Data": "` before and `"}` after the current response, it would be valid JSON. Only, instead of having your original JSON returned, it would be a JSON object that has a string (that string being JSON itself).

**What you want to do instead** is unencode the JSON string returned from `http://somelinkhere/`. So, instead of this code:

```
data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
MarketDataMap[index] = string(data)
```

... you'll want to use [the JSON Unmarshal() function](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal), like this:

```
rawData, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
data := make(map[string]interface{})
err := json.Unmarshal(rawData, &data)
// Handle err here

MarketDataMap[index] = &data
```

Comment: No, where you put `// Handle err here` - if I handle the error, it jumps into there immediately. Meaning `if err != nil `

Comment: `json: Unmarshal(nil)`

Comment: Close but no cigar :o( `json: Unmarshal(non-pointer map[string]interface {})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162545/discussion-between-cbll-and-anonymous-penguin).